# Parsing Json string C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON string but I am getting an odd error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty'

Would you check it and let me how I can get `title` values from this JSON string!

```
[
   {
      "id":"14962106",
      "title":"Why is Yahoo called Yahoo",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Why_is_Yahoo_called_Yahoo",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"65001091",
      "title":"Connecting yahoo IM to yahoo",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Connecting_yahoo_IM_to_yahoo",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"45440021",
      "title":"Why doesn't Yahoo recognize my Yahoo account",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Why_doesn%27t_Yahoo_recognize_my_Yahoo_account",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"264383657",
      "title":"How is Yahoo different from Yahoo Mail",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/How_is_Yahoo_different_from_Yahoo_Mail",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"11230021",
      "title":"Does Yahoo block email",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Does_Yahoo_block_email",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"11230461",
      "title":"Is yahoo answers gone",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Is_yahoo_answers_gone",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"12097857",
      "title":"What is Yahoo BrowserPlus",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/What_is_Yahoo_BrowserPlus",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"100301924",
      "title":"Is yahoo answers useful",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Is_yahoo_answers_useful",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"107057666",
      "title":"Are yahoo emails free",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Are_yahoo_emails_free",
      "is_answered":true
   },
   {
      "id":"107858033",
      "title":"Is yahoo games free",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.answers.com\/Q\/Is_yahoo_games_free",
      "is_answered":true
   }
]
```

---

```
JArray theamackersSuggesionResult = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject parsedObject in theamackersSuggesionResult.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in theamackersSuggesionResult)
    {
        string propertyName = parsedProperty.Name;
        if (propertyName == "title")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parsedProperty.Value.ToString());
            KeywordSuggestionTable.Rows.Add(parsedProperty.Value.ToString());
            KeywordResultDataGrid.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you create a model for the json, and use Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a model,

```
public class Example
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("link")]
        public string link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_answered")]
        public bool is_answered { get; set; }
    }
```

and use Newtonsoft to get the models from the json

```
var responseModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json);
```

Then you can loop the `responseModels` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this site -> http://json2csharp.com/

If you want to get model in C# of JSON data this site will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to this line:

```
foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in theamackersSuggesionResult)
```

It should be:

```
foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in parsedObject.Properties())
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9dC3n